# Cannot click on "Save as" link/button using selenium webdriver in chrome browser

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium webdriver automation in c# for chrome browser. Here i have requirement - i have to save pdf document/html page. so what i am doing is ..right clicking and then trying to move till "Save as" but its not working. I have used below code for that-

Comment: Please define "Not working". Any errors? Also, post the complete code you have at the moment.

Comment: Selenium cannot interact with system windows and prompts, only with web pages!

Comment: i am not getting any error from above code but "document is not getting saved" .

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments mentioned, Selenium Webdriver can't send keys to the file dialog itself.
But with the following code you can send this to the active window, in your example Chrome:

```
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 SendKeys.SendWait("^s");  // send control+s
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 SendKeys.SendWait("fileName{ENTER}"); // sends "fileName then enter
```

The Thread.Sleep is for the fact that chrome has time to open the filesave dialog. Be careful this code can't change the location.

Comment: @ LzyPanda ..Perfect working thank you